# 2D Camera movement script throwing CS0428

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a camera to move whenever you press either WASD or the arrow keys, but it's throwing

> Error  CS0428  Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type 'Transform'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

On this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameramover : MonoBehaviour
{        
    public Camera controlled;
    Vector3 movement;

    void Start()
    {
        Transform transform1 = controlled.GetComponent<Transform>;
    }

    void Update() 
    { 
        movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0.0f);

    }
}
```

I tried invoking the method, but that threw CS0201, so I tried doing 
`new Transform(controlled.GetComponent<Transform>;)`
and that didn't work either, so I went here to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of the wonderful people at the Game Dev Network discord server! i just had to add a pair of parentheses on the end of the controlled.GetComponen;